# Parse: parse performance if we have 50000 rows in a table

Tags: parse-platform, nosql

Does parse take equal time to any amount of load data or it varies based on size? I expect to have 20k to 50k records in a table for SAAS project.

If you can give me this meta information then I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The time is influenced by record count. But, it's also influenced by [indexes](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/smart-indexing-at-parse/) and the type of query you're doing. 50k records isn't a particularly large set, but it really depends on the data and the query as to how it will perform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so it means parse can be used for big data?

Comment: Right now i have 12 tables includes reference keys  (foreign keys) and i can't use parse pointers & relationship because the ObjectIds are not accessible when we are working offline.

Comment: Medium data. Hundreds of thousands or rows and you'll probably start to see issues unless you have great indexes. pointers basically are foreign keys

Comment: but problem in parse is when a user is offline and while creating PFobject we are not able to get objectId. ObjectId is returned only when the object is saved on parse but in my case i want user to fully add/update in offline mode and later sync. Which creates issue in sync process since the app is customized.

Comment: When we use pointer then it can only be linked with ObjectId which i don't get when offline. Any idea?

Comment: Fine. I haven't actually tried locally saving instances linked by pointer and saving them later

Comment: Hello Wain, do you know why PinInBackground takes more than 5 seconds for a single object? i am facing this issue.